# Sub-1 GHz Narrow Band vs Wide Band

Tags: rf, communication, 433mhz

As per the [TI document](http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/swry006/swry006.pdf?DCMP=ep-con-lprf-sub1range&HQS=ep-con-lprf-sub1wpaper-b-whip-de) I came across which compares narrow band sub-1 usage vs wide band sub-1 usage mentions a concept called coding gain and its disadvantages.

Because of my lack of understanding in S1G I do not understand certain statements made in this document. e.g.

> 1. "Using coding gain does not improve the sensitivity nor range, it simply is another way of representing data"
> 2. "Given the same net data rate/throughput, narrowband and coding gain systems will have similar range." How come?
> 3. " Adding more coding gain will not help, as then you need to either reduce the net data rate or increase the RXBW to fit the signal. "
> 4. "Trading higher receive sensitivity for less spectrum efficiency (higher bandwidth) by spread spectrum" How can we achieve higher receive sensitivity using code gain?

I would appreciate help to better understand such statements made on this document. Your explanatory answers and time are much appreciated.

Comment: Although I'm not an expert, it seems like this article is comparing apples and oranges as a prelude to a little sales-pitch. It appears like the TI article tries to make coding gain sound like a bad thing... which it clearly isn't... You want to be able to verify if a code is valid, and if you use an ECC code to do that you get a coding gain. Although the article probably is correct that coding gain is limited in its energy efficiency, the article does a bad job at clarifying the concepts or what "coding gain systems" or codes they are looking at. Me, I would probably look away from this.

Comment: At this point of time for my research I believe there is something for me to take from that document. I agree, I too feel like its written in such a way. 

What did you mean verify a code is valid? Which code did you refer? is it transmitted data you meant?

If in that case, how come veryfying such data with a code would provide a "gain"?

Comment: I mean to verify that data is valid. In an ECC code you add a few bits of data and, in case of just a few bit errors in transmission, you are able to recover one or more bits depending on the code. This gives a "gain in SNR" (reduction in BER). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_gain

Comment: so transmitting a metadata like code that can be used to recover from errors is called code gain? Cant we do that in narrow band communication too? We could transmit the data and then the code that will help recover from errors. Why do we need wider band for that?

Comment: Exactly, you don't need a wider band to use a code with coding gain. But I believe wide band transmission needs to stay below FCC limits, thus it is more dependent on "coding gain". That is not to say wide band communication doesn't have it's uses (e.g. UWB radar). It's just very different.